# cakephp advance filter using between

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, between

I need an advanced filter like eCommerce website. When I select a check box it need to display the data from selected range. So I created some check boxes which store values like 2-4, 4-8, 8-50 and so on.

To set filter condition, I wrote the following code

```
if(!empty($this->request->data['filter']['workinghrs'])) {
    $workinghrsdata = array();
    foreach($this->request->data['filter']['workinghrs'] as $v) {
        $conditions[]['Gig.workinghrs BETWEEN ? AND ?'] =explode('-', $v);
    }
}
```

Which generate this sql.

`Gig`.`workinghrs` BETWEEN 2 AND 4 AND `Gig`.`workinghrs` BETWEEN 4 AND 8

But I want to set OR operator as the position of AND. So query should be like,

`Gig`.`workinghrs` BETWEEN 2 AND 4 OR `Gig`.`workinghrs` BETWEEN 4 AND 8

How to solve this?

Comment: This looks suspiciously like [a previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31668374/how-to-add-multiple-between-in-cakephp) asked again.

Comment: @AD7six now the issue resolved but thanks you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `OR` index to conditions array -

```
$conditions['OR'][]['Gig.workinghrs BETWEEN ? AND ?'] =explode('-', $v);
```

Comment: I added but following code print only last check box value so i wrote $conditions['OR'][]['Gig.workinghrs BETWEEN ? AND ?'] =explode('-', $v); and know its working thanks alot genius pls update your answer too.